# Blazor SignalR issue

Tags: blazor, signalr

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to resolve this problem, I have setup another SignalR hub in my blazor Server application and am getting the following failure when tryign to access the page that the SignalR hub is supposed to be connected to for auto updates.

Error:

```
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at RevIntra.UI.Base.Pages.Revroof.RevbendOrderListViewPage.OnInitializedAsync() in D:\Shared\Source\Repos\Revroof\RevIntra_BP\RevIntra\Shared\RevIntra.UI.Base\Pages\Revroof\RevbendOrderListViewPage.cs:line 75
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

My code kicks off from the follwing..

```cs
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
         userInfo = await ((IdentityAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider).GetUserViewModel();
         _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/revbendorderhub"))          
             .WithAutomaticReconnect()
             .Build();
         _hubConnection.On<AXOrderHeader>("ReceiveMessage", (orderHeader) =>
         {
             int index = this._messages.FindIndex(x => x.OrderDid == orderHeader.OrderDid);
             if (index >= 0)
             {
                 if (orderHeader.OpenOrder)
                 {
                     this._messages[index] = orderHeader;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     this._messages.RemoveAt(index);
                 }
             }
             else if (orderHeader.OpenOrder)
             {
                 this._messages.Add(orderHeader);
             }
             StateHasChanged();
         });

         await _hubConnection.StartAsync(); <--- Call to intialise hub
         loadCompleted = true;
     }
```

The module that it is failing in is the inbuilt HubConnection class at this point:

```cs
     private async Task StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         await _state.WaitConnectionLockAsync(token: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
         try
         {
             if (!_state.TryChangeState(HubConnectionState.Disconnected, HubConnectionState.Connecting))
             {
                 throw new InvalidOperationException($"The {nameof(HubConnection)} cannot be started if it is not in the {nameof(HubConnectionState.Disconnected)} state.");
             }

             // The StopCts is canceled at the start of StopAsync should be reset every time the connection finishes stopping.
             // If this token is currently canceled, it means that StartAsync was called while StopAsync was still running.
             if (_state.StopCts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
             {
                 throw new InvalidOperationException($"The {nameof(HubConnection)} cannot be started while {nameof(StopAsync)} is running.");
             }
             using (CancellationTokenUtils.CreateLinkedToken(cancellationToken, _state.StopCts.Token, out var linkedToken))
             {
                 await StartAsyncCore(linkedToken).ConfigureAwait(false); <-- here is where it is failing
             }
             _state.ChangeState(HubConnectionState.Connecting, HubConnectionState.Connected);
         }
         catch
         {
             if (_state.TryChangeState(HubConnectionState.Connecting, HubConnectionState.Disconnected))
             {
                 _state.StopCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
             }
             throw;
         }
         finally
         {
             _state.ReleaseConnectionLock();
         }
     }
```

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info here to troubleshoot. The error seems to say that the problem is RevbendOrderListViewPage.cs:line 75

What I have done to troubleshoot SignalrR issues is to:

1. Use the Dev Tools in the browser to inspect the WebSocket packets.
2. Use Fiddler to inspect the incoming and outgoing signalr traffic.
3. Enable the Azure SignalR monitor to view the logs. Used the local
4. Azure SignalR Service emulator.

Hopefully this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am not getting this error anymore, I now get a 401 Unathorized?

Comment: Hard to say...I ran into a 401 unauthorized problem in a Blazor app that was secured using Microsoft.Identity.Web - my controller was adding a bearer token to the Signalr calls which caused a problem. What helped me was to start super simple. Get it working then add complexity. For a 401, I would use Fiddler to view the actual http request that caused the 401. It might give you some clues. Plus you can view the full response which might be a login page.

Answer (score 0):

Have decided to drop this approach, I am really interested in what's going on in the database so I am going to implement a timer that refreshes that database every 30 seconds.